# display specific lines in all files in a directory in linux

Tags: linux, sed

I have 200 text files in folder F. I want to see lines 2-4 of all files. I have tried something like:

`$sed -n '2,5'p *.txt`

but it only reads the first file. Can anybody please help?

Furthermore, I might need to send these lines to a new file, something like:

`$sed -n '2,5'p *.txt>path`

My knowledge of linux is basic, so if you have a totally different solution, please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FNR>1&&FNR<5' *.txt > result.txt
```

Comment: 1-is it possible to send lines go to different files? for example lines from fine foo.txt--->newfoo.txt

Comment: 2-for the case of awk 'FNR>1&&FNR<5' *.txt, is it possible to see the name of the corresponding file right before the lines?

Comment: both are possible,awk has FILENAME variable

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ns '2,4p' *.txt > results.txt
```

If you just want to capture the results:

```
sed -ns '2,4w results.txt' *.txt
```

Another way to see and capture the results:

```
sed -ns '2,4!b;p;w results.txt' *.txt
```

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Invoking-sed) for the `s` invocation option.

Comment: This is what I get 
sed: illegal option -- s
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: @NavidWu is your version of sed GNU?

Comment: It's OSX 10.9.5, I hope this answers your question

Comment: @NavidWu my solution depends on a GNU sed extension (as stated).